# Swift add array of objects as map annotations

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, mkannotation, cloudkit

I have an array of objects that I'm getting from my CloudKit database that is being returned as an array of location() objects.

location() is defined as...

```
class location {
var title: String?
var subtitle: String?
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}
```

I need to be able to create annotations from the array, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

When I try to pass the array as an MKAnnotation it says it doesn't conform properly, though it does have all of the data needed to conform, I just can't figure out how to get it out of the array and into annotations.

My class

```
class Locations: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
var title: String?
var subtitle: String?
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

override init()
{
    self.title = "Test Title"
    self.subtitle = "Test Subtitle"
    self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init()
}
}
```

in my view controller "objects" is created...
    `var objects = [Locations]()`

This is the part of the fuction that I use to get the data from CK and store it in an object ...

```
for locations in results! {
                let newLocation = Locations()
                newLocation.title = ckData["Name"] as? String
                newHaunted.subtitle = ckData["Subtitle"] as? String
                let location = ckData["Location"] as! CLLocation

                self.objects.append(newLocation)
```

Lastly I call a function in ViewDidAppear that has the following code...

```
    let locationsToAdd = objects
    mapView.showAnnotations(locationsToAdd, animated: true)
```

At this point I'm getting an empty array from objects.  If I try to use Locations() instead of objects it says it can't convert it to MKAnnotation, which it should already be.

The following is the function that I use to get the data from CloudKit.

```
func getRecordsFromCloud() {
// Fetch data using Convenience API
let cloudContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
let publicData = cloudContainer.publicCloudDatabase
let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Locations", predicate: predicate)

publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { results, error in
    if error == nil { //no error
        for locations in results! {
            let newLocation = Locations()
            newLocation.title = locations["Name"] as? String
            newLocation.subtitle = locations["Subtitle"] as? String
            let location = locations["Location"] as! CLLocation

            let newLocationCoords: CLLocationCoordinate2D = location.coordinate
            newLocation.coordinate = newLocation
            self.objects.append(newHaunted)


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
                self.locationsTable.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }
    else {
        print(error)
    }
}
}
```

After this I call getRecordsFromCloud() in viewDidLoad.

Comment: It's convention to use capitalized names for types: "Location", not "location"

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact error message and post the code where the error occurs (if not in the snippet already posted).

Comment: Sorry, I do use capitals in the code, I had just re-typed it here without as an example.
And I'm not getting an error, I'm simply not getting any annotations added.  Please see my comment below for more info.

Comment: Please also share the code where you add annotations on the map.

Comment: Well, are you sure that your `objects` array is populated with data from Cloud Kit when `viewWillAppear` is called? You should add the annotations after that for loop is completed

Comment: Actually, when I try to print the data right after showAnnotations I'm getting what I assume is an empty array. "[]"

I don't understand this because I use the same "objects" to get the data for the tableview which works fine.

Comment: Tableview works differently, you can check out a tutorial about it. But here you must be sure that you call `addAnnotations` after the `objects` array is populated.

Comment: Okay, I call the function to add the annotations in viewDidAppear which happens above were I fill the object.  But the actual function for adding the annotations is after I fill the object.

Comment: The fact that you get `[]` which is an empty array when you print it says it does not happen in the right order. I think the array filling happens on a background thread. If you share the whole part of the array filling code I could help you more.

Comment: Try to put `addAnnotations` just after that for loop

Comment: I will add the entire function for getting the cloudkit dat and filling the array to the original post.  One moment please.

Comment: `performQuery` happens asynchronously on a background thread. Tableview works because of the `dispatch_async(get_main...` which reloads the table with the new data once the array is populated by calling `reloadData()`. You should call `addAnnotations` just below `reloadData()`, because that block of code is executed on the main thread after the array is filled. You should check out some tutorials on GCD and swift closures if you want to have a greater understanding of what is actually happening there.

Comment: That got it!

I"m going to read more about it and try to understand it.  Thanks so much for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify that your class conforms to a certain protocol you must use `class ClassName: ProtocolName` notation. So in your case you should replace `class location` with `class location: MKAnnotation` to tell the compiler that your class conforms to `MKAnnotation` protocol.

Comment: I"m working with bits of code that I've got from tutorials and Github.  My class has the MKAnnotation protocol, but it also has the NSObject protocol, like so...
`class location: NSObject, MKAnnotation {...`

While I do define title, subtitle and coordinate in my class, I only have the data in the array and not the property name, so I thought maybe that was a problem for the MKAnnotation...

Comment: That seems good. What does not work then? What error do you get?

Comment: I have a mapview and a tableview in my viewcontroller.  I can get the data from the object and into the tableview without issue using object[indexPath.row].  But when i try to use the object to add annotations to the map I get nothing added at all.  I've tried addAnnotations() and showAnnotations(), but nothing is ever added to the map.

Comment: Could you update the question with the code you use?

Comment: Yes, give me a moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @Jelly's suggestion or just declarare that your class conforms (implements) `MKAnnotation` with an extension:

```
extension Location : MKAnnotation 
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your `Location` class like so:

```
class Location: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    let title: String?
    let subtitle: String?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(title: String?, subtitle: String?, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.coordinate = coordinate

        super.init()
    }
}
```

Then you can add annotations to your map like so:

```
let annotation = Location(title: name, subtitle: locality, coordinate: coordinate)
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Clearly, you'd set the `title` and `subtitle` however you want, but hopefully this illustrates the idea.